# Invalid AssignmentOperator while converting from C++ to Java

Tags: assignment-operator

I'm java programmer, but I used to use C++ long time ago. Now I have to translate form C++ to Java one program and I found one line, wchich I don't know what does it mean:

```
if (wr[m-2] == 0) wr[m-1] == 0;
```

Program works correctly in C++, but of course there's an AssignmentOperator error in Eclipse.

Comment: Are you sure you copied that correctly? It doesn't seem to contain any assignment operator. I'd have expected it to be `wr[m-1]=0;`. In any case, we probably need to see a bit more code to say anything meaningful -- just for example, knowing the type of `wr` would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're checking

*Based on wr being an array of ints and m being an int, if the array wr is equal to 0 at index m-2, then check if the wr at index m-1 is equal to 0.*

That line looks right, but you might want to check that your minus signs are actually minus signs and not a different-but-similar type of hyphen. Otherwise it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

The lines you quoted result in a no-op where there likely should be an assignment.

```
if (wr[m-2] == 0)
    wr[m-1] == 0;
```

should probably be

```
if (wr[m-2] == 0)
    wr[m-1] = 0;
```